# Imagick readImage falling into system error event blackhole

Tags: php, imagemagick, wamp, imagick

I am trying to get imagick installed (by far not an easy task, but helped enormously using the [filter] on https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html) and running on my WAMP/Windows10/PHP7.0 webapp, but I am running into a black-hole on the readImage() call (the log file only goes up to 'checkpoint 2').

Looking at the Windows system events log I can see an Error Level Application event reading:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.23.0, time stamp: 0x5776399f
Faulting module name: php_imagick.dll, version: 7.0.10.0, time stamp: 0x58927660
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000002468c
Faulting process ID: 0x4ba8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d44f71d980b2f3
Faulting application path: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.18\ext\php_imagick.dll
Report ID: 1b3f5a6d-ed31-4fae-b73d-ebf0d17e9c94
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This bug comes when running the following code via my WAMP

```
<?php
class Test  {
public function doTrace($msgTx) {
    $dt=date('[D M d H:i:s Y]', gmdate(time()));
    error_log($dt.$msgTx."\n",3, "C:/test.log" );
}
public function doTest() {
    $fn='C:/test.pdf'; 
    if ( file_exists($fn) ) {
        $im = new Imagick();
        $this->doTrace("checkpoint 1");
        $im->setResolution(300, 300); 

        $this->doTrace("checkpoint 2");
        $im->readImage($fn."[0]");    //[0] for the first page

        $this->doTrace("checkpoint 3");
        $im->setImageFormat('png');

        $this->doTrace("checkpoint 4");
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        echo $im;

        $this->doTrace("checkpoint 5");
    }
    else {
        echo "Did not find $fn";
    }
}
}

$try = new Test();
$try->doTest();

?>
```

This is me simply trying a version of the manual entry for readImage (http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php#116812), so what is wrong here? Have I installed Imagick wrongly (php_imagick-3.4.3-7.0-ts-vc14-x64) or is it something else? (Note, I can make IM work on some simple tests)

My phpinfo() reads:

```
 imagick
 imagick module enabled
 imagick module version 3.4.3
 imagick classes    Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
 Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version  ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 2016-03-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
 Imagick using ImageMagick library version  ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 2016-03-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
 ImageMagick copyright  Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
 ImageMagick release date   2016-03-27
 ImageMagick number of supported formats:   234
 ImageMagick supported formats  3FR, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CLIPBOARD, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPS, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EMF, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FITS, FPX, FRACTAL, FTS, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, GV, H, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JP2, JPC, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPM, JPS, JPT, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAGICK, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCREENSHOT, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBP, WMF, WMV, WPG, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

Thanks

Abe

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and know what line the error is occurring? For example if the error fires off at this `$im = new Imagick();` when you are trying to instantiate Imagick then something is probably wrong with your Imagick configuration/install. If it errors when trying to read/manipulate a file then the file may be corrupt and Imagick doesn't know what to do and so it segfaults. HTH

Comment: the problem is on the readImage() call (the error log goes up to "checkpoint 2"; I can open the PDF via Foxit Reader with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with no obvious solution, I decided to try a different direction and see if I could run the convert command through the commandline. This pushed me onto having to install Ghostscript (https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html).

Now that Ghostscript is installed it seems that the PHP is now working - I get an image of the first page of the PDF.

Did I miss this on the installation instructions (I do not recall seeing Ghostscript being mentioned)?

A